# jQuery update div the moment a table is updated

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to figure out a way to have jQuery update a div the moment a table in mysql is updated. I've spent a vigorous amount of hours searching online for an answer, and so far, nothing. Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Comment: This could be very complicated or fairly simple depending on how and where you update the database, can we see some of your code?

Comment: @amosrivera - I was thinking the same.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately, my code is deleted out of frustration, however, I can give you detail on what I plan to do. Everything will automatically update through a user's activity. For instance, if someone adds a comment on a post, that person will get a notification through a mysql table (I created a table called notifications).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the steps you should probably take are:

Have a piece of AJAX code that queries the server for a change (like row count changing or something along those lines).    Using jQuery you can do that:

```
function checkUpdates()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'hasDataChanged.php',   // a webservice or other URL that queries the database
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            // return a JSON string like { "hasChanged" : "true" } or something
            if (data.hasChanged) {
                 // data has changed, do something
            }
        }
     });
}
```

Then you can use the Javascript method `setInterval` to call the code every few seconds.  It is unrealistic to do it instantly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval("checkUpdates()", 3000);  // Calls the function every 3 seconds
});
```

Comment: You know, something I haven't been successful with is getting a return from the AJAX call. Can you explain it to me briefly? I tried reading it on the jQuery site, but it's not stating it in a simple way. What do I do in the PHP file to get the result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now you are asking a very generalized common question.  I think you need to read some beginner tutorials on AJAX, jQuery and PHP.  Writing a polling application will be overwhelming for you if you aren't even comfortable with basic AJAX requests.  Try reading some tutorials there are thousands out there on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to poll the database via ajax and php every (couple of) second(s) and check if the data has changed. if so, update the div.
i don't think there's a way of detecting the exact moment the db is updated.

Comment: I did something like that before, where I would have the div refresh every 5 seconds, and when the table is updated, so would the div. I didn't really like it, because it constantly had activity going on the server side, and that could be problematic, or so I would imagine.

Comment: Well the database is on the server so you have to keep communicating with it if you want to know what it's doing.  The server can't talk to your webpage, it only goes one way.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure that's what StackOverflow does to check for new answers while you have a question open.  Other sites like Gmail and HuffingtonPost also use the technique to check for new data so it's a very common practice and you shouldn't be afraid of it as long as you keep the amount of data you're transferring back and forth small.

Answer (score 0):

Useful links on polling. It attempts to make server send data to browser:

- http://onepixelahead.com/2010/04/30/html5-web-sockets-example/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))