# How to refresh the Server or Database Table Values for every X Seconds

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ok i am tryin to make a Chatting application where users can chat with each other if theyr logged in to the website. I have set up everything except a little working which i am not able to write.

In my example : 2 users are chatting with each other : User A and User B

When User A submits a comment in the Chat Window , then the whole div containing the Comments should be refreshed not only at User A's side but also at User B's side so that when User A submits the comment, User B should be able to see it.

In short refreshing the div on every users page when a new record is added to the database table.

Im good in PHP, Jquery, AJAX.

Comment: Check out this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604129/jquery-update-div-the-moment-a-table-is-updated/7604207#7604207

Comment: in short you guys must be knowing how facebook's LIVE notifications work. each time a user does something. a new record is prepended to the live notifications div. and on a status if someone comments, the user on the other side also see's the comment straight away even though he doesnt refresh the page. it is something related to "refresh the div if a new record is added" . but im not able to achieve that effect after long hours of coding. 

P.S : I need a simple Ajax + PHP code. coz im sure its something small but im not able to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're comfortable restricting your users to new technologies, your best bet is to look into HTML5 `websocket` API. It's still a bit green around the gills, but it's certainly the way these things will be done in the near future. Kaazing's default example is a chat client, actually.

On the server side, there are implementations for websockets in JavaScript (Node.js), Java, and other technologies, but I'm not sure about PHP.

If you don't want to use websockets, research techniques that fall under the name "COMET" or search for "long polling". These will be far more responsive than a time interval.

If on the other hand you don't need it to be super-responsive, you could just use `setInterval` to have both clients poll the server for changes.

Comment: in short you guys must be knowing how facebook's LIVE notifications work. each time a user does something. a new record is prepended to the live notifications div. and on a status if someone comments, the user on the other side also see's the comment straight away even though he doesnt refresh the page. it is something related to "refresh the div if a new record is added" . but im not able to achieve that effect after long hours of coding. 

P.S : I need a simple Ajax + PHP code. coz im sure its something small but im not able to get the result.

Comment: Hard to describe how annoying it is to see that same comment copy+pasted across each answer. ;-) We have all given you valid answers. Make your Ajax request in a setInterval call (say, every 1000 milliseconds?) for a resource-intensive yet snappy response time. There are no miracles... only websockets offers duplex communication with the sever. Everything else is a clever variation on polling the server for new data.

Comment: im really sorry for the cop + paste but u should understand how irritated i am on my self to not achieve this. sorry for annoying u :)

Comment: ok i have learnt how ajax push works . but did not get a tutorial on it. and would like to know how to write scripts on the server side. I got to know how facebook accomplished it from here [link]https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=496077348919[link]

Answer (score 2):

Every x seconds use Ajax to check for new messages and if there is a new message, write it in the div.

There is no way for the server to tell the client a new message was posted. The client has to ask the server.

Comment: in short you guys must be knowing how facebook's LIVE notifications work. each time a user does something. a new record is prepended to the live notifications div. and on a status if someone comments, the user on the other side also see's the comment straight away even though he doesnt refresh the page. it is something related to "refresh the div if a new record is added" . but im not able to achieve that effect after long hours of coding. 

P.S : I need a simple Ajax + PHP code. coz im sure its something small but im not able to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

DC's answer is correct, if you are looking for an AJAX polling solution.  This could be done with a simple JavaScript Interval.

However, polling is not light on resources as there are going to be a lot of duplicate content requests - and you would need to poll frequently to make the chat feel as though it is real-time.

If you would like to push data to the client from the server, I would look into writing this application using web sockets.  NodeJS would be perfect for what you are trying to achieve, depending on what browsers you are wanting to support.

Comment: in short you guys must be knowing how facebook's LIVE notifications work. each time a user does something. a new record is prepended to the live notifications div. and on a status if someone comments, the user on the other side also see's the comment straight away even though he doesnt refresh the page. it is something related to "refresh the div if a new record is added" . but im not able to achieve that effect after long hours of coding. 

P.S : I need a simple Ajax + PHP code. coz im sure its something small but im not able to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

you need a timeout function like so:

```
 function updateChatWindow(){
    var xhr = $.ajax({
       url : /* controller url */,
    })
    .done(function(response){
       /** do something with the response the server gave you back **/
    });
     .fail(function(response){
      /** handle a lost connection is some way, maybe show a message to the user, or retry request */
    })
    .then(function(){
        periodicRefresh();
    });
 }


var timeoutFunction; //idealy, this will be inside a javascript object
//starts a refresh (in 500ms)
function periodicRefresh(){
    timeoutFunction = setTimeout(updateChatWindow,500);
}
//stops the refresh from happening, see below why
function clearRefresh(){
    clearTimeout(timeoutFunction);
}

var inputElement = $(/** the input area where the user types text **/);
inputElement.keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==13){ // or whatever the e.???==13 was to check for enter
        clearRefresh();
        /** submit new chat line **/
        updateChatWindow();
});

updateChatWindow();
```

Recap:

1) Have a ajax call that will update the window
2) Have a timer function that will store within it a timeout variable that will trigger a refresh of the content (the ajax call from 1)
3) Have the ability to cancel that request (because users type text, and after they hit enter, you should refresh the chat window no matter what)
4) Have the ability to stop the timeout function somehow to allow 3) to happen.

Comment: in short you guys must be knowing how facebook's LIVE notifications work. each time a user does something. a new record is prepended to the live notifications div. and on a status if someone comments, the user on the other side also see's the comment straight away even though he doesnt refresh the page. it is something related to "refresh the div if a new record is added" . but im not able to achieve that effect after long hours of coding. 

P.S : I need a simple Ajax + PHP code. coz im sure its something small but im not able to get the result.

Comment: The code above does the ajax part of the update. The way you get your data from the database and how you send it is basic SQL and JSON on the PHP end, and it's design dependent. 

The div update part is a simple jQuery selection and manipulation. What I showed you here is the actual UI flow needed for "live" refresh of the chat window. It's up to you how you implement the rest.